# communication between related process objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipc

I am trying to write an application that launches another application and sends messages(json data) to it.

I can launch the task through NSTask and NSPipe but it seems its only possible to launch the task and read its output in the Parent. What is the best way to do otherwise? i.e Launch a task and send message to that task?

What is the best way of communication between related/non-related processes on the same machine in objective-C?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NSTask` has a property `standardInput`, you can send input.

Answer (score 0):

The current gold standard for Inter-Process Communications (IPC) on macOS is XPC. XPC is a fast, reliable, service that's (relatively) easy to set up and use in Objective-C/Swift. Once connected, your application obtains a proxy object connected to an actual object in the service process. All you have to do to run code in your service is send a message to your proxy (i.e. `[remoteService doSomething:@"with this data"]`—the message gets magicaly encoded, sent to the service process, and executed.

The caveat is this: all of this is easy to use *if* you create an XPC Service. An XPC Service is a sub-program you compile and bundle with your application. If you do that, `launchd` handles launching your service, creating the XPC connection, and connecting it to your application. All you have to do is tell the XPC Services API to start your service and start calling methods.

You can read all about creating XPC services in the [Creating XPC Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) section of the *Daemons and Services Programming Guide*. There are also several example projects that illustrate how this is done.

If that fits your needs, you are good to go.

On the other hand, if you want to launch an arbitrary process and establish an XPC connection with that, things get decidedly more complicated. I actually spent the better part of a year poking at this problem until I found a solution. No one at Apple would ever tell me, directly, that there was a way to do this. I suspect this has security implications which is (a) why Apple only makes it easy to use bundled XPC services and named XPC services (registered with `launchd`) and (b) why Apple employees won't talk about alternative connection methods.

My recommendation is to look into XPC services. If that will solve your problem then that is, by far, the best solution.

If you absolutely *must* communicate with an arbitrary process you launched by other means (not `launchd`), then post again and I can share the details. Warning: this is non-trivial, and you still have to create a launchd service, so if your goal is to avoid that, you're out of luck.